# KeyError trying to multiply item in a tuple by item in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My python assignment asks me to make a list of tuples and multiply an item in each tuple by a value in a dictionary and I keep getting a KeyError, but I don't really know why or how to fix it. I might just be doing everything wrong.

```py
shop_prices = {
    'eggs': 1.99,
    'milk': 0.99,
    'ham': 4.99,
}

cart = [('eggs', 2), ('milk', 4)]

itemprice = int(cart[0][1]) * shop_prices[item]
print(itemprice)
```

I also have to add all these values together at the end, so if you could help me with that too that would be so great.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show shop_prices and item please?

Comment: A key error is likely due to the value of the item variable

Answer (score 1):

Does that answer the question?

```py
for item, value in cart:
    print(shop_prices[item] * value)
```

And if you want total price

```py
total = sum(shop_prices[item]* value for item, value in cart) # you may need to round up the value...
```

Comment: Yes, that was so helpful! Thank you!